# Call functions that are inside a running thread

Tags: python, multithreading

I have this code:

```
def Spawn(nick,password):
    Active=True

    s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.connect(('asdasd',asdasdasd))
    s.send('PASS '+password+'\r\n')
    s.send('NICK '+nick+'\r\n')
    s.send('JOIN '+channel+'\r\n')

    while True:
        buf=s.recv(1024)
        if('PRIVMSG' in buf):
            sender=buf.split('!',1)[0].split(':')
            message=buf.split(':',2)[2].replace('\n','')
            if(sender[1]==owner):
                if(sender[1]==owner):
                    if(message.strip()=='!stop'):
                        Active=False
                        print '('+nick+')'+' has been disabled'
                    else:
                        if(message.strip()=='!start'):
                            Active=True
                            print '('+nick+')'+' has been enabled'
                        else:
                            if(Active):
                                print 'sent'

lines=tuple(open('accts.txt', 'r'))

for line in lines:
    data=line.split(' ',1)
    t=threading.Thread(target=Spawn,args=(data[0].replace('\n',''),data[1].replace('\n','')))
    t.start()
```

I need to be able to run `s.send('asdasdasd\r\n')` outside of the thread but I cant find much info on this

If it's possible I'd like to be able to define which thread I want to call the function on also

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do here? If you send data to a socket from different threads you will have to synchronize these. In addition you probably need to make sure that the data is sent in the correct order. Shouldn't it be easier to send all data from the same thread?

Comment: How would I make the right amount of sockets if its based on the lines in a file?